# How exactly do you go about creating an onboarding screen, that only appears once at first launch? (Swift/swiftui)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I know how to make views, etc, which is the majority of the questions and videos I found, but how exactly do I make the onboarding view appear only once?

Can I use CoreData? Json files? UserDefaults?

Comment: UserDefaults should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **UserDefaults**.

Best way is to store a **boolean value** like '*onboardingViewWasShown* (true/false)' in UserDefaults.standard and then anytime your app starts, look into UserDefaults.

If TRUE -> nothing to do, if FALSE, show your **onboarding view** and then set TRUE to your UserDefaults for the next time our app is being launched.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            
            if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "KeyOnBoardingViewShown") == false {
                // show your onboarding view
                OnboardingView()
                
                // set the value for next call
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "KeyOnBoardingViewShown")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made the code example for SwiftUI -> You can call such If-Statements within the body prroperty this code must be INSIDE ContainerView like VStack.